# Why on vue 3 watch is not called on object mutation?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

Could you explain why `watch` is not called when I mutate the object in Vue 3.
Instead I need fully replace object.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-glade-zer8v?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

```js
  methods: {
    change() {
      // Triggers watch
      this.user = { ...this.user, name: "hello" };
      // Doesn't triger watch
      this.user.name = "hello";
    },
  },

  watch: {
    user(nextUser) {
      console.log(nextUser);
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`watch` docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/instance-methods.html#watch):

> To also detect nested value changes inside Objects, you need to pass in `deep: true` in the options argument

Use the `watch` [object syntax](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-data.html#watch) which has a `handler` method, and use the `deep` property:

```js
watch: {
  user: {                        // Watch object syntax
    handler(nextUser) {          // method must be called `handler`
      console.log(nextUser);
    },
    deep: true                   // deep watch for nested property changes
  },
}
```